# Discord.py welcome bot on_member_join event not getting callded

Tags: discord, discord.py

I've been interested in working with discord bots lately, and from what I'm seeing this code should work but it is not...
I'm simply just playing around with the API because it's fun so I'm pretty new with this. I just want the bot to welcome someone when they join.

```
import discord

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))
    channel = client.guilds[0].get_channel(CHANNEL ID)
    await channel.send("Bot online")

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('$hello'):
        await message.channel.send('Hello!')

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    print(f'{member.name} has joined the server')
    channel = client.guilds[0].get_channel(CHANNEL ID)
    print(channel)
    await channel.send(f'{member.name} has joined the server')

@client.event
async def on_member_remove(member):
    print(f'{member.name} has left the server')
    channel = client.guilds[0].get_channel(CHANNEL ID)
    print(channel)
    await channel.send(f'{member.name} has left the server')

client.run('TOKEN HERE')
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors at all? Is you `on_ready()` firing? I don't really see why this wouldn't work. PS. consider using `commands` with a `prefix` instead of manually parsing every message (`if message.content.startswith...`)

Comment: My on_ready event is firing, but nothing else is. This exact code has been tested on another system and it works fine. I don't know why it wouldn't work on mine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**FOR discord.py >= 1.5**

1.5 adds support for [Gateway Intents](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html), by default your bot doesn't have access to guild members like it did in previous versions.  If your bot is in less than 100 servers then you can enable these intents without verification.  You should see these settings at the bottom of your Bot page on the Discord Developer Portal.  If you enable both, then you need to change your Client (or commands.Bot) instantiation as such:

```
intents = discord.Intents.all()
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
```

<s>When I test this, the event is firing, but I'll bet your issue lies in the line:</s>

```
channel = client.guilds[0].get_channel(CHANNEL ID)
```

It will be far more reliable to just use use [client.get_channel](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=get_channel#discord.Client.get_channel) to ensure you are actually grabbing the intended channel, all channel IDs on discord are unique so you do not need to use a guild object.  Also `CHANNEL ID` will not be a valid variable, but I am guessing you just redacted it.

Comment: I have tested and I can't get it to fire either, even if the only line it should fire is a print line. I suspect there is some caveat to whether or not this fires that we don't understand.

Comment: If I copy your code exactly, change all of your `client.guilds[0].get_channel` to just `client.get_channel` all of your events work for me

Comment: Does your bot have send messages permission in the target channel?

Comment: You're right about the redacted thing. Despite that, my on_ready event is firing, but nothing else is. This exact code has been tested on another system and it works fine. I don't know why it wouldn't work on mine

Comment: What versions are you running? I have it working with discord.py 1.4.1, Python 3.8.5

Comment: dwrw I'm running discord.py 1.5 and py 1.8.5

Comment: Okay I think I've figured this out, so discord.py 1.5 adds support for the new [Gateway Intents](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html).  When I update to 1.5 I can replicate your issue.  I've been told that you can enable the `Server Members Intent` in your developer portal settings, but I have yet to get this to work so far.  The other option is to downgrade to 1.4.2

Comment: I have updated my answer with more detailed information, I got the Intents to work after actually reading the docs, doh!

Comment: Okay, new error.

intentss = discord.intents.all()
client = discord.Client(intents==intents)

using this code and getting the error:
    intents = discord.intents.all()
AttributeError: module 'discord' has no attribute 'intents'

Comment: in discord.intents.all() "Intents" is capitalized

Comment: Yea I realized that but there's a new problem. Using the fixed code a new error:

`client = discord.Client(intents==intents)
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`

Edit: I just fully read your answer my bad.

Comment: Just needs one equals sign buddy, you could've just copy pasted what I put....

Comment: I just encountered this on an old bot running `discord.py` 1.4.1, intents need to be enabled on the discord developer site for things like `on_member_join` to continue to work, even on older versions of `discord.py`. (No code changes are needed in 1.4.1, just enable the intents)

Answer (score 1):

instead of member.name use member and if that dosnt work add this where you have your variables intents = discord.Intents(messages = True, guilds = True, reactions = True, members = True, presences = True)
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '*', intents = intents)

Answer (score -1):

You forgot the brackets for the decorators.

```
@client.event
```

should be

```
@client.event()
```

EDIT: Not it, apparently. Will update this answer when OP replies with more information.

Comment: I don't think that's the problem here. If it were, the user wouldn't be getting their on_ready event firing and they'd post a problem about that. I write events with no brackets in the decorators all the time. Probably shouldn't be, but I do.

Comment: Just tested that & it only works in your `main` file, it instantly crashes inside `Cogs`. I guess you're right, but you really shouldn't have such a huge main file (assuming you do, as you said you do it "all the time").

Comment: discord.py `event` decorators do not have parenthesis, but things like `command` decorators do require them

Comment: My on_ready event is firing, but nothing else is. This exact code has been tested on another system and it works fine. I don't know why it wouldn't work on mine.