# discord.py on_raw_reaction_remove(payload) passing user_id as none

Tags: python, heroku, discord, ibm-cloud, discord.py

I've written a script to assign roles when a server member reacts using a certain emoji, but when hosting the code in Heroku or ibm cloud none is the value for user_id.

Sepcifically, it seems like `member = guild.get_member(payload.user_id)` is assigning none into member variable when using the payload from `on_raw_reaction_remove()`.

Adding a role using `on_raw_reaction_add()` works as expected.

```
#import discord lib
import discord
#import commands from discord lib
from discord.ext import commands

#set client variable to use disocrd commands
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = ".")

#start event and check Bot is ready
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is ready.")

#upon detecting a reaction event assign the role which matches the reaction emoji
#see https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?#rawreactionactionevent
@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    message_id = payload.message_id

    #check if the message id matches the message id of the "assign your role!" message in discord
    if message_id == 123456789:
        #get the server name from the payload
        guild = client.get_guild(payload.guild_id)
        #get the member name from the payload
        member=(payload.member)

        #Debugging
        Post_Message = "Add(1/3) - Message ID matches."
        Post_Message = Post_Message+"'"+str(guild)+"'"+" is the Guild ID."
        Post_Message = Post_Message+"'"+str(member)+"'"+" is the Member ID."
        print(str(Post_Message))

        #if the name of the reaction emoji is "League" theen assign the "League bois discord role
        if payload.emoji.name == "League":
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="League bois")
        else:
        #set role variable to the name of the reaction emoji
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name=payload.emoji.name)

        if role is not None:
            
            #debugging
            print("Add(2/3) - Attempting to assign Role...")
            
            if member is not None:
                #add the role
                await member.add_roles(role)
                #Debugging
                print("Add(3/3) - Role has been assigned.")
            else:
                print("Member not found.")
                print("Member returned is: "+str(member))
        else:
            print("Role not found.")
            print("Role Returned is: "+str(role))
```

But removing a role using `on_raw_reaction_remove()` doesn't work when hosted in Heroku or ibmcloud. It works successfully when ran locally.

```
#upon detecting a a reaction emoji being removed, remove the appropriate role on discord
@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_remove(payload):
    message_id = payload.message_id

    # check if the message id matches the message id of the "assign your role!" message in discord
    if message_id == 123456789:
        #get the server name from the payload
        guild = client.get_guild(payload.guild_id)
        # payload.member is not availible for REACTION_REMOVE event type
        member = guild.get_member(payload.user_id)

        #Debugging
        Post_Message = "Remove(1/3) - Message ID matches."
        Post_Message = Post_Message+"'"+str(guild)+"'"+" is the Guild ID."
        Post_Message = Post_Message+"'"+str(member)+"'"+" is the Member ID."
        print(str(Post_Message))

        # if the name of the reaction emoji is "League" theen assign the "League bois discord role
        if payload.emoji.name == "League":
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="League bois")

        else:
            # set role variable to the name of the reaction emoji
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name=payload.emoji.name)

        if role is not None:
            
                    
            #Debugging
            print("Remove(2/3) - Attempting to remove Role...")
            

            if member is not None:
                #remove the role
                await member.remove_roles(role)
                #Debugging
                print("Remove(3/3) - Role has been removed.")
            else:
                print("Member not found.")
                print("Member returned is: "+str(member))
        else:
            print("Role not found.")
            print("Role Returned is: "+str(role))

#bot token goes here
client.run("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")
```

If I add and then remove a reaction I get the following locally

```
Add(1/3) - Message ID matches.'test big XD haha lol' is the Guild ID.'daz#6949' is the Member ID.
Add(2/3) - Attempting to assign Role...
Add(3/3) - Role has been assigned.
Remove(1/3) - Message ID matches.'test big XD haha lol' is the Guild ID.'daz#6949' is the Member ID.
Remove(2/3) - Attempting to remove Role...
Remove(3/3) - Role has been removed.
```

but this in IBM Cloud and Heroku

```
APP/PROC/WEB    0   Add(1/3) - Message ID matches.'test server' is the Guild ID.'daz#6949' is the Member ID.    Sep 30, 2020, 9:55:07 PM
APP/PROC/WEB    0   Add(2/3) - Attempting to assign Role... Sep 30, 2020, 9:55:07 PM
APP/PROC/WEB    0   Add(3/3) - Role has been assigned.  Sep 30, 2020, 9:55:07 PM
APP/PROC/WEB    0   Remove(1/3) - Message ID matches.'test server' is the Guild ID.'None' is the Member ID. Sep 30, 2020, 9:55:08 PM
APP/PROC/WEB    0   Remove(2/3) - Attempting to remove Role...  Sep 30, 2020, 9:55:08 PM
APP/PROC/WEB    0   Member not found.   Sep 30, 2020, 9:55:08 PM
APP/PROC/WEB    0   Member returned is: None    Sep 30, 2020, 9:55:08 PM
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using discord.py 1.5.0?

Comment: Ill bet you have 1.4.x installed locally, and heroku is pulling the newest version, 1.5.  You will either need to freeze discord.py to version 1.4.2, or if you want to use 1.5 see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64142666/4984749) on gateway intents.

Comment: @derw You are 100% correct. I had 1.4.1 installed locally. Installed 1.5.0 and replicated results from Heroku/IBM.
Followed your answer in your link and now working. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

derw is correct.

I had discord.py 1.4.1 installed locally.
Ran `py -3 -m pip install -U discord.py` and installed 1.5.0. After install my results were consistent between local and remote (IBM/Heroku).
Followed derw's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64141932/discord-py-welcome-bot-on-member-join-event-not-getting-callded/64142666#64142666) and enabled Privileged Gateway Intents on the Discord Developer Portal (*Presence Intent* and *Server Members Intent*), then replaced this

```
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = ".")
```

with this

```
intents = discord.Intents.all()
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
```

Thanks derw!